# Selenium By.xpath, By.linkName worked before, now it's not working anymore

Tags: java, html, selenium, xpath, web

Here is the html code for which I'm trying to click the link:

```
class="MainMenuBody" valign="top">

        <a href="https://portal.regify.com/phpCreateRegify.php">Create regimail online</a><br>
```

And here is the code:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(@href, 'phpCreateRegify.php')]")).click();
```

I have tried also with this `driver.findElement(By.linkText("Create regimail online")).click();` and by partial link text, even tried `driver.switchTo().defaultContent();` but nothing seems to work. It worked a  few weeks ago, but know it doesn't. Any other ideas, suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked if your Webdriver is still on the correct page where this element is located?

I've had a similar problem once, where due to changes on the website, the element I was looking for was moved to another site and I had to adjust my code.

So try to navigate to the site where that element is located step by step.
Worked for me.